# Hard drive shows as full after reformatting / partition alignment, what to do?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ext4

I have a 8 TB drive that previously was a Windows formatted NTFS drive.
On this drive I have a large file that has a size of 7 TB (7.696.581.394.432 Bytes).

I switched my OS to Linux and noticed that `fdisk -l` told me that the partitions are not aligned. I reformatted the drives with the correct alignment and with ext4 file system format.

I moved all the files back on to the drive with `rsync`. I did not notice anything strange. It did not bring up any warning or error.

Now my drive shows up as being full with 0 Bytes of free space. The drive shows up as having 7.937.399.177.216 Bytes. I moved ~200 GB of files off the drive except for the aforementioned large file. But the drive still shows up as full. I can't write anything to the drive. I fear that my data is getting corrupted since something is very off here.

Any advice on what is going on and what I could do would be great. I had already mirrored that drive so there is no other backup... I don't want to loose my images and documents.

Output for `df -HT /dev/sda1`:

```
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4  8,0T  7,7T     0 100% /media/archive
```

Output for `du -h -s /media/archive/*`:

```
7,1T    /media/archive/data
16K     /media/archive/lost+found
```

Output for `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 7,28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model: ST8000AS0002-1NA
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 15628053134 15628051087  7,3T Linux filesystem
```

Output for `df -i`:

```
Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      244191232     12 244191220    1% /media/archive
```

Output for `sudo lsof +L1`:

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NLINK  NODE NAME
pulseaudi  816  spe    6u   REG    0,5 67108864     0 30384 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
pulseaudi  823  gdm    6u   REG    0,5 67108864     0 31009 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)
Xorg      1029  gdm   23u   REG    0,5        4     0 33053 /memfd:xshmfence (deleted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the filesystem there is some space reserved for root processes. That means that you might see the 100% and 0 available but there is actually space to use, if you are root.

So, what you could do is copy the rest of the files as root, if I understood your problem.

If you want to know why there is space reserved for root, check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why), that even has a quote from a kernel developer on the issue.

So, you still have some space left, but not for normal users. When the disk is 94% you will be able to see some free space for normal users.

You can check this by creating a filesystem and filling it up, for example:

```
# create a 10M disk
dd if=/dev/zero of=mytestdisk bs=1M count=10

# format it to ext4
/usr/sbin/mkfs -t ext4 mytestdisk

# mount it
sudo mount mytestdisk MOUNTPOINT

# put a big (disk-wise) file in
dd if=/dev/zero of=/MOUNTPOINT/fillitup.txt bs=1M count=8
```

If you run a `df` now you will see this:

```
S.ficheros     bloques de 1K   Usados Disponibles Uso% Montado en
[...]
/dev/loop0              8887     8364           0 100% /MOUNTPOINT
```

Although this will work (as root):

```
sudo date > /MOUNTPOINT/date.txt
```

While this will not (as a normal user):

```
date > /MOUNTPOINT/date.txt
```

Comment: I will look into how I can change that limit. 5% of 8TB are 400 GB... that is insane.

Comment: I just changed it to 1% and now I have free space: `tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 0):

> I switched my OS to Linux and noticed that fdisk -l told me that the partitions are 
>   not aligned. I reformatted the drives with the correct alignment and with ext4 file 
>   system format.

Alignment is a process that is operating on partitions.
Formating does not heal alignment mismatches because it operates within partitions.
You should describe what you really did.

Comment: Yes, I know. Since I was also repartitioning I did also change the file system from NTFS to ext4.
The issue seems to be the reserved blocks that suggest that the drive is full while it isn't. With NTFS this was not an issue but now with ext4 it is. I reduced the size of the reserved blocks as a solution.